# Connect to laravel sail mysql from macOS local machine

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I have installed a fresh Laravel 8 Project using sail
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-macos

I followed the guide. First ran this

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
```

Then this

```
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

But now I have difficulty connecting using mysql client. This is the command that I'm trying to execute

```
mysql -u sail -D example_app -h localhost -P 3306 -p
```

I get the following error

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'sail'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 0):

The .env file at the root of the project – docker-compose.yml automatically detects and imports the content of this file. For instance, in the MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}' line, the container's MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD environment variable will receive the value of DB_PASSWORD from the .env file.

By default these are **sail** for the username and **password** for the pass. Are you passing that password when connecting?

This is a really good article i followed to get more insights: https://tech.osteel.me/posts/you-dont-need-laravel-sail

Answer (score 0):

Use DB_HOST as 'mysql' in .env file.